# What can I do to connect Wireguard VPN over mobile data when connection over wifi is working on IOS14

Tags: wireguard, apple-ios

I have set up a wireguard tunnel between my IPhone 6s and a public server.
I am using the Wireguard app on IOS 14.4.2

Iphone has the following configuration:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <hidden>
ListenPort = 31194
Address = 10.0.0.2/32, fd99::10:0:0:2/128
MTU = 1280

[Peer]
PublicKey = <hidden>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24, fd99::a00:0/112
Endpoint = 139.xxx.xxx.203:31194
PersistentKeepalive = 10
```

Conncecting to a server with the following configuration:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.0/32
Address = fe80::acee:f99a:4d29:582f/64
Address = fe80::d290:fbfc:499f:a91/64
Address = fe80::2546:b195:41d4:3dfc/64
Address = fe80::3c03:6787:b98a:5864/64
Address = fe80::122f:f5fb:3510:8f18/64
Address = fe80::d44f:b466:97b1:d2a4/64
MTU = 1280
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 31194
PrivateKey = <hidden>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <hidden>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32
Endpoint = 88.xxx.xxx.208:31194

[Peer]
PublicKey = <hidden>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
Endpoint = 88.xxx.xxx.208:31194
```

The other peer in my local network and the IPhone on wifi on the same network connect correctly. However, when wifi is off and the phone is using 4G data the handshake to the server does not complete.

As you can see I have tried lowering the MTU, but this seems to have no effect - have I done this correctly?

Google suggests that the mobile network may be on ipV6,so I tried adding ipV6 addresses - again are these correct? However, according to ipv6-test.com my connection isn't ipV6.

Mobile network is SMARTY in UK (Part of the The Three Network). Other users report being able to use wireguard successfully on this network.

Any suggestions for other changes I could try?